# Position absolute element is the child of the page, instead of the position relative element

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I want a tiny icon to be placed on the top left of an image, but when I write top: 0 and left: 0, the icon is placed on the top left of the entire page, so I have to scroll all the way up to see it.

This is the image's CSS:

```
.attimage {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
  position: relative;
}
```

This is the icon's CSS:

```
.location-icon {
  width: 15px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the image & the icon in a container which will have the position property set to `relative`.

The icon can then be positioned in absolute inside this container

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

make div warping your image and icon with `position: relative;` and put icon & image on it.